# Как настроить русский язык в Ubuntu Server 15.04?

Tags: ubuntu

В консоле вместо русских букв отображаются иероглифы (не квадратики - это я так понял другая проблема). Гугл отсылает к настройкам локали.

Что я уже сделал:

1) Установил пакеты с русским языком

2) Проверил список локалей - ru_RU.utf8 там есть

3) Посмотрел настройки текущую локаль, там написано так: LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8

Не пойму куда копать дальше... Кто-то знает что по данной проблеме?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Попробуйте установить пакет поддержки кириллицы для консоли

```
sudo apt-get install console-cyrillic
```

После установки добавьте в файл /etc/rc.local перед exit 0

```
cyr
```

Перезагрузите ОС. Должно помочь.

Answer (score 7):

Обычно при проблемах в консоли с русским языком пользуюсь этими командами:

```
locale-gen ru_RU.UTF-8
dpkg-reconfigure locales
sudo apt-get install console-cyrillic
```

Answer (score 2):

Проблему решили так (для ubuntu 15.04 и выше):

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup

UTF-8 → и выбрал Cyrillic - KOI8-R and KOI8-U → Fixed → далее как есть.
```

Потом прописываем в `/etc/profile` в конец `setupcon --force`

Это чтобы не было ошибки при заходе в иксы (отключаем проверку - в консоли мы или нет).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте также запустить

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

выбрав UTF-8 и "кириллица - славянские языки".